# Bootstrap carousel is not functioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Attempting to create a bootstrap carousel inside a container-fluid div. However, when the page loads the slides are stacked on top of each other and all buttons on the carousel are unresponsive, and the next and previous arrows are not visible.

The code used for the carousel is from the bootstrap website here:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Social Wall</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/build/css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/d7Aezk/slider1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/iPHRek/slider2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/kTW8s5/slider3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonGroup">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="manualBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Manual</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="twitterBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Twitter</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button id="instagramBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Instagram</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button id="loadMore" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Load More</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: bootstrap `JS` lib is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

**Note:** You are missing `bootstrap.min.js` library.

Here is demo link: https://output.jsbin.com/huhedecuyo

https://jsbin.com/huhedecuyo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Social Wall</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/build/css/styles.css">
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#carouselExampleIndicators').carousel({
            interval: 2000,
            pause: "false"
        });
      });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/d7Aezk/slider1.jpg" alt="First slide">
                </div>
               <div class="item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/iPHRek/slider2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://preview.ibb.co/kTW8s5/slider3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
             </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonGroup">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="manualBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Manual</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="twitterBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Twitter</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button id="instagramBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Instagram</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <button id="loadMore" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Load More</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to include bootstrap js file..

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`